# Umbraco multiple imagepicker-objects efficiently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, umbraco7

we're creating a Umbraco-admin-extension, and we need a couple of image-pickers. The first one was easy, but know we're adding more, it seems there should be a more efficient solution to this.

This is what we had:

```
    <umb-control-group label="Logo">
      <ul class="unstyled list-icons" ng-if="logoNode">
        <li>
            <i class="icon icon-delete red hover-show pull-right" ng-click="removePicture()"></i>
            <img src="{{logoNode.thumbnail}}" />
            {{logoNode.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="unstyled list-icons">
        <li>
            <i class="icon icon-add blue"></i>
            <a href ng-click="openMediaPicker()" prevent-default>Select</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </umb-control-group>
```

And the javascript was:

```
$scope.openMediaPicker = function() {
  dialogService.mediaPicker({ callback: populatePicture });
}

function populatePicture(item) {
  $scope.logoNode = item;
  $scope.contentData.logoID = item.id;
}
```

But now, we have more Image Picker objects.
I've tried passing a parameter with the "openMediaPicker()" call. But I can't pass it through to the populatePicture() function.

So I ended up using a switch within my openMediaPicker() function, and creating a populatePicture() function for each Image Picker object, and calling it from within the switch. It's terrible, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it efficient.

edit to clarify: I have multiple property-editors of the same type on one page.

Any clues?

Comment: Do you want multiple pickers in the same property editor?  Or are you saying that when you have multiple properties of this type on a Content item, they are calling the same method somehow?

Comment: I have multiple properties of this type of content item yes.